# Breaking cycles in RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

Sample app: I have two independent pieces:

- A counter 1-10
- A list that displays all words loaded from a file that have that many letters

Now the way it would work is:

- The counter would be an `Observable<Integer>` that emits numbers 1-10
- The list display would use a `WordFileService.load(n)` to load the list of words asynchronously
- After the list is loaded, it should notify the counter to emit the next number

In other words, there's a cycle here - the source emitter depends on the completion of target emitter and vice versa.

Also consider a more complex case where the source emitter depends on the result of the target emitter as well. E.g. say that the number emitter would take the number of words emitted and emit the next number of the same parity (e.g. if the next number to be emitted is 5 and the number of words loaded is 36, it would skip over 5 and emit 6, since `6 mod 2 == 36 mod 2`).

It might be even easier to think in terms of any multi-player games turn-based games. E.g. consider chess. One player starts, the other responds based on their move, then the first player responds back based on the second player's move and so on. So we'd have 2 `Observable<PlayerMove>` or something along those lines that would have a circular relationship.

I assume I can use BehaviorRelay from [RxRelay](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay), but I'm not sure if that's the best approach, given the discussion in [this issue](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/issues/7).

So my question is: what is the best way to accomplish this in RxJava (including changing the workflow if that's the best solution)?

Comment: It sounds like the "notify to emit" should really be backpressure.

Comment: @chrylis Hm... That's a good observation, never thought about it in those terms and it might be something to consider in the original case. However I've edited the question to actually make it fully circular. I.e. consider a more complex case where the inputs fully depend on the previous output.